# Javascript go backwards by integer

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Normal For Loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < someNumber; i++)
```

however I want to be able to do this:

```
for (var i = someNumber; i == 0; i-=3)
```

So, we start with `i = someNumber`, this is the highest value.
We then test for `i == 0` hitting 0.
Finally we subtract 3, `i-=3`

How do we do this in JavaScript?

Don't worry about `someNumber`, I do `firstNumber % 3` before I start iterating back through.

Comment: Have you tried your solution? It should work fine. (Of course depending on `someNumber` value, since the loop might be indefinite if subtraction by `3` on each step never hits 0.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See the demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/ymvun/1/)

```
function hello(){
    for (var i = 100; i > 0; i-=3){
        console.log(i);
    }
}
hello();
```

Comment: Cheers, knew it was something simple, just need to make sure all the loose ends are tied up

Answer (score 4):

You need something like this:

```
for (var i = someNumber; i > 0; i-=3)
```

The condition in the middle is the condition for the loop to **continue**, not for the loop to terminate.

(You might need to tweak it a bit - because you're stepping down by `3` at a time, that loop will allow `-1` or `-2` through.  A condition of `i > 2` might be what you need.)

Answer (score 2):

The problem with this loop is that i-=3 may never reaches zero. e.g.
if somenumber=10, the counter will iterate through 10, 7, 4, 1, -2 etc.

you need:

```
for (var i = someNumber; i >= 0; i-=3)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `i == 0` returns just false.. 
You should use

```
for (var i = someNumber; i > 0; i-=3)
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to reduce the counter by 3 every step?
ex: 9, 6, 3, 0

then the middle part should be 
î != 0
or better yet î > 0 if counter may be any arbitrary number and not divisible by 3